# TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) code taken from pluralsight course

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am viewing the Pluralsight course on Python. At the end of the module we are to write a Python script. The author does not show how to create two of the scripts. I have them coded as the follows:

main.py

```
from hs_student import *

james = HighSchoolStudent("james")
print(james.get_name_capitalize)
```

student.py

```
students = []


class Student:
    school_name = "Springfield Elementary"

    def __init__(self, name, s_id=332):
        self.name = name
        self.s_id = s_id
        students.append(self)

    def get_name_capitalize(self):
        return self.name.capitalize()
...
```

hs_student.py

```
import student as student

students = []


class HighSchoolStudent(student):

    school_name = "Springfield High School"

    def get_school_name(self):
        return "This is a High School student"

    def get_name_capitalize(self):
        original_value = super().get_name_capitalize()
        return original_value + "-HS"

...
```

When running the code, I get an error. From my understanding, I am passing too many arguments to the `get_name_capitalize` function. How can I fix this?

The error message is:

```
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This code:

```
class HighSchoolStudent(student):
```

is trying to inherit from the `student` module, not the `student.Student` class. Change it to:

```
class HighSchoolStudent(student.Student):
```

to inherit from the intended class.

Comment: Or, instead of using 'import student', use 'from student import Student', then start your class with 'class HighSchoolStudent(Student)'.  Not sure which is preferable, but the import thing is that student is a module, not the class that you want to subclass.

Comment: @JohnDeighan: Yeah, that works. I was minimizing changes to the code (only one line has to change, not two), but any way you want it works. It always gets confusing when you name module and the sole class in it the same thing, so I sometimes favor the approach I gave in the answer to be extra explicit about it being a class from the module by using the fully qualified name.

Comment: You saved my day. I was busy refactoring a few files, and had moved an import that said "from . import Feed" - which was the module, not the class. Then my attempt to initialise the child class, XFeed ("class XFeed(Feed)") kept failing with the subjected error. Turns out Feed was imported as the module, and not the class within it..